# ActionController::RoutingError uninitialized constant

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

My Rails app works fine in development and pushes to Heroku without error, but when I try:

```
heroku open
```

the heroku log shows the above error. I have checked the case and pluralisation of my controller (called static_pages), so no problem there. I have run

```
heroku run rake db:migrate
```

My routes.rb file contains

```
root 'static_pages#home'
```

so the issue can't be that. Anything simple that I may be missing here?

As requested, the full stack trace is:

> 2017-11-29T15:56:56.587399+00:00 app[web.1]: F,
>   [2017-11-29T15:56:56.587041 #4] FATAL -- :
>   [94718486-1b0a-4dea-aeb0-7a26060201d2]
>   2017-11-29T15:56:56.587686+00:00 app[web.1]: F,
>   [2017-11-29T15:56:56.587397 #4] FATAL -- :
>   [94718486-1b0a-4dea-aeb0-7a26060201d2] ActionController::RoutingError
>   (uninitialized constant StaticPagesController):
>   2017-11-29T15:56:56.561616+00:00 app[web.1]: I,
>   [2017-11-29T15:56:56.561491 #4]  INFO -- :
>   [94718486-1b0a-4dea-aeb0-7a26060201d2] Started GET "/" for
>   94.119.64.15 at 2017-11-29 15:56:56 +0000 2017-11-29T15:56:56.587764+00:00 app[web.1]: F,
>   [2017-11-29T15:56:56.587693 #4] FATAL -- :
>   [94718486-1b0a-4dea-aeb0-7a26060201d2]
>   2017-11-29T15:56:56.588311+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   [94718486-1b0a-4dea-aeb0-7a26060201d2]
>   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:269:in
>   `block in constantize' 2017-11-29T15:56:56.588313+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   [94718486-1b0a-4dea-aeb0-7a26060201d2]
>   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:267:in`
>   inject' 2017-11-29T15:56:56.588315+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   [94718486-1b0a-4dea-aeb0-7a26060201d2]
>   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:582:in `get' 2017-11-29T15:56:56.588312+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   [94718486-1b0a-4dea-aeb0-7a26060201d2]
>   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:267:in`
>   each' 2017-11-29T15:56:56.588314+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   [94718486-1b0a-4dea-aeb0-7a26060201d2]
>   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:267:in
>   `constantize' 2017-11-29T15:56:56.588316+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   [94718486-1b0a-4dea-aeb0-7a26060201d2]
>   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/http/request.rb:85:in`
>   controller_class_for' 2017-11-29T15:56:56.588318+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   [94718486-1b0a-4dea-aeb0-7a26060201d2]
>   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:43:in
>   `controller' 2017-11-29T15:56:56.588319+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   [94718486-1b0a-4dea-aeb0-7a26060201d2]
>   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:50:in`
>   block in serve' 2017-11-29T15:56:56.588309+00:00 app[web.1]: F,
>   [2017-11-29T15:56:56.588201 #4] FATAL -- :
>   [94718486-1b0a-4dea-aeb0-7a26060201d2]
>   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:269:in
>   `const_get' 2017-11-29T15:56:56.588317+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   [94718486-1b0a-4dea-aeb0-7a26060201d2]
>   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/http/request.rb:78:in`
>   controller_class' 2017-11-29T15:56:56.588320+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   [94718486-1b0a-4dea-aeb0-7a26060201d2]
>   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:33:in
>   `each' 2017-11-29T15:56:56.588321+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   [94718486-1b0a-4dea-aeb0-7a26060201d2]
>   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:33:in`
>   serve' 2017-11-29T15:56:56.588316+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   [94718486-1b0a-4dea-aeb0-7a26060201d2]
>   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:613:in `constantize' 2017-11-29T15:56:56.588323+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   [94718486-1b0a-4dea-aeb0-7a26060201d2]
>   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.3/lib/rack/etag.rb:25:in`call'
>   2017-11-29T15:56:56.588326+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   [94718486-1b0a-4dea-aeb0-7a26060201d2]
>   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.3/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:232:in
>   `context' 2017-11-29T15:56:56.588325+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   [94718486-1b0a-4dea-aeb0-7a26060201d2]
>   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.3/lib/rack/head.rb:12:in`call'
>   2017-11-29T15:56:56.588334+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   [94718486-1b0a-4dea-aeb0-7a26060201d2]
>   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:36:in
>   `call_app' 2017-11-29T15:56:56.588332+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   [94718486-1b0a-4dea-aeb0-7a26060201d2]
>   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:59:in`
>   call' 2017-11-29T15:56:56.588328+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   [94718486-1b0a-4dea-aeb0-7a26060201d2]
>   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:613:in
>   `call' 2017-11-29T15:56:56.588319+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   [94718486-1b0a-4dea-aeb0-7a26060201d2]
>   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:29:in`
>   serve' 2017-11-29T15:56:56.588324+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   [94718486-1b0a-4dea-aeb0-7a26060201d2]
>   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.3/lib/rack/conditional_get.rb:25:in
>   `call' 2017-11-29T15:56:56.588328+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   [94718486-1b0a-4dea-aeb0-7a26060201d2]
>   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:26:in`
>   block in call' 2017-11-29T15:56:56.588330+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   [94718486-1b0a-4dea-aeb0-7a26060201d2]
>   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:97:in
>   `run_callbacks' 2017-11-29T15:56:56.588339+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   [94718486-1b0a-4dea-aeb0-7a26060201d2]
>   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:69:in`
>   block in tagged' 2017-11-29T15:56:56.588333+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   [94718486-1b0a-4dea-aeb0-7a26060201d2]
>   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:31:in
>   `call' 2017-11-29T15:56:56.588343+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   [94718486-1b0a-4dea-aeb0-7a26060201d2]
>   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:25:in`
>   call' 2017-11-29T15:56:56.588343+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   [94718486-1b0a-4dea-aeb0-7a26060201d2]
>   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.3/lib/rack/method_override.rb:22:in
>   `call' 2017-11-29T15:56:56.588347+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   [94718486-1b0a-4dea-aeb0-7a26060201d2]
>   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.3/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:111:in`
>   call' 2017-11-29T15:56:56.588342+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   [94718486-1b0a-4dea-aeb0-7a26060201d2]
>   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:79:in
>   `call' 2017-11-29T15:56:56.588322+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   [94718486-1b0a-4dea-aeb0-7a26060201d2]
>   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:834:in`
>   call' 2017-11-29T15:56:56.588331+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   [94718486-1b0a-4dea-aeb0-7a26060201d2]
>   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:24:in
>   `call' 2017-11-29T15:56:56.588340+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   [94718486-1b0a-4dea-aeb0-7a26060201d2]
>   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in`
>   tagged' 2017-11-29T15:56:56.588346+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   [94718486-1b0a-4dea-aeb0-7a26060201d2]
>   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:125:in
>   `call' 2017-11-29T15:56:56.588350+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   [94718486-1b0a-4dea-aeb0-7a26060201d2]
>   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/puma-3.10.0/lib/puma/server.rb:437:in`
>   process_client' 2017-11-29T15:56:56.588348+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   [94718486-1b0a-4dea-aeb0-7a26060201d2]
>   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:522:in
>   `call' 2017-11-29T15:56:56.588345+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   [94718486-1b0a-4dea-aeb0-7a26060201d2]
>   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:27:in`
>   call' 2017-11-29T15:56:56.588344+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   [94718486-1b0a-4dea-aeb0-7a26060201d2]
>   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.3/lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in
>   `call' 2017-11-29T15:56:56.588335+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   [94718486-1b0a-4dea-aeb0-7a26060201d2]
>   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in`
>   block in call' 2017-11-29T15:56:56.588351+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   [94718486-1b0a-4dea-aeb0-7a26060201d2]
>   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/puma-3.10.0/lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:120:in
>   `block in spawn_thread' 2017-11-29T15:56:56.588327+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   [94718486-1b0a-4dea-aeb0-7a26060201d2]
>   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.3/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:226:in`
>   call' 2017-11-29T15:56:56.588346+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   [94718486-1b0a-4dea-aeb0-7a26060201d2]
>   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in
>   `call' 2017-11-29T15:56:56.588349+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   [94718486-1b0a-4dea-aeb0-7a26060201d2]
>   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/puma-3.10.0/lib/puma/server.rb:605:in`
>   handle_request' 2017-11-29T15:56:56.588341+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   [94718486-1b0a-4dea-aeb0-7a26060201d2]
>   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:69:in
>   `tagged' 2017-11-29T15:56:56.588341+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   [94718486-1b0a-4dea-aeb0-7a26060201d2]
>   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in`
>   call' 2017-11-29T15:56:56.588348+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   [94718486-1b0a-4dea-aeb0-7a26060201d2]
>   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/puma-3.10.0/lib/puma/configuration.rb:225:in
>   `call' 2017-11-29T15:56:56.588350+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   [94718486-1b0a-4dea-aeb0-7a26060201d2]
>   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/puma-3.10.0/lib/puma/server.rb:301:in`
>   block in run'

Code for static_pages_controller.rb

```
class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController

def home
end

def about
end

def contact
end

end
```

and for routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

get '/about', to: 'static_pages#about'

get '/contact', to: 'static_pages#contact'

root 'static_pages#home'


resources :articles do
resources :comments
end


end
```

Comment: Please share the full error stacktrace

Comment: Add the code for your `static_pages_controller`.

Comment: And your routes.rb as well

Comment: Where is you `StaticPagesController` file. Have you rebooted the server after changing routes? For some reason, the server cannot find that controller. What is the filename?

Comment: Have you set the proper launch command for rails in your `Procfile` ?

Comment: It is located in app/controllers/static_pages_controller.rb

Comment: I didn't explicitly set any Procfile launch command, do you need to for rails, as I have deployed to Heroku before without doing so.

Comment: I would add one just to be safe. Try adding `web: bundle exec rails server -p $PORT` to a Procfile located in your project root

Comment: Afraid i'm stiil getting the same errors as before after having committed the Procfile